# Интернет магазин (Доска объявлений)

Tags: php

Создал доску объявлений на PHP, работает отлично, теперь надо добавить функцию "поднять в горячие", так как раньше не сталкивался такой функцией, хочу спросить есть ли готовые скрипты? Или же коды?

Comment: раз вы все создали, в чем проблема досоздать то, что вам нужно? Если вы писали сами, то что-то готовое под вашу логику навряд-ли существует.

Comment: И что вообще значит "поднять в горячие"?

Comment: как в OLX, платишь деньги, а они тебе твой товар поднимут в топ

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментатору, если Вы писали сами, то должны знать что и как. А вот если нет, то сдесь не то место чтобы задавать такие вопросы